# Software for creating lines of equal traveling time on streets from given point

Tags: maps

In a usual route planner software like google maps you can specify a point A, let it calculate the shortest path to a point B and get an estimated traveling time. However is there a software which does the following:

Specify a point A and draw an area around A which contains all points B where the traveling time (shortest time for a car on streets) from A to B (1:1 routes – i.e. always the same A with only one B, *not* the [Traveling Salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem)) is less than a given time T (e.g. T = 15 min).

I am interested in maps for germany if that matters.

If possible this software should also be able to avoid highways in for the calculation. I am also interested in this for bicycle or public transport (such as google maps already offers it for just two points A and B).

The software should be gratis and run on linux, on the web or on windows.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403699/map-of-all-points-below-a-certain-time-of-travel) stack overflow question including a number of web sites that allow you to do this and software that uses the Google API - your best bet is probably [How Far Can I Travel](https://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-can-i-travel.htm)

Example from a random address in Germany for 1 hours public transport:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I wanted: In "how far can I travel", you have to specify a time AND speed or a distance (which is essentially the same). I want to specify only a time, i.e. the program should use different speeds for different types of streets just as google maps does it for two points A and B.

Comment: This is no longer offered due to the increase in price for Google Maps API access.